# Using AddIpAddress()/DeleteIpAddress() with info from GetAdaptersAddresses()

Tags: c, winapi

I need to change the IP address and submask of a specific network interface from a C/C++ program. In Windows documentation, I have found that I should use [`AddIPAddress()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/iphlpapi/nf-iphlpapi-addipaddress)/[`DeleteIpAddress()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/iphlpapi/nf-iphlpapi-deleteipaddress) from the Windows API. However, `DeleteIpAddress()`, for instance, requires a `NTEContext` as a parameter. I have found [an example](https://github.com/microsoft/Windows-classic-samples/blob/main/Samples/Win7Samples/netds/iphelp/ipchange/IPChange.Cpp) that uses [`GetAdaptersInfo()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/iphlpapi/nf-iphlpapi-getadaptersinfo) to get the index of the interface and context. However, the page also explicitly states that:

> On Windows XP and later:  Use the GetAdaptersAddresses function instead of GetAdaptersInfo.

But, while `GetAdaptersInfo()` populates an `IP_ADAPTER_INFO` struct in which the index/NTEcontext are present, [`GetAdaptersAddresses()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/iphlpapi/nf-iphlpapi-getadaptersaddresses) provides an `IP_ADAPTER_ADDRESSES` struct in which there are no such members.

What should I do with the newer `GetAdaptersAddresses()` function to get the index/context for interfaces?

Comment: Do you need to remove an IP address that you didn't add?

Comment: `AddIPAddress()`/`DeleteIpAddress()` only work for IPv4, but `GetAdaptersAddresses()` supports IPv6. Try using `[Create|Delete]UnicastIpAddressEntry()` and related functions instead. They accept information that you can get from `GetAdaptersAddresses()`, `GetUnicastIpAddressTable()`, etc

Comment: @SolomonUcko yes, because i want to change programmatically the ip / netmask of the address.

Comment: @RemyLebeau I have noticed there is a method `SetUnicastIpAddressEntry()`.
I have filled the  `InterfaceIndex`member of  an initialized `MIB_UNICASTIPADDRESS_ROW` struct with the `IfIndex` of the target interface (got using `GetAdapterAddresses()`) and the `Address.Ipv4` field with a custom ip. The `MIB_UNICASTIPADDRESS_ROW` struct is passed to the method, but ip does not change. What am I missing ?

Comment: `GetAdaptersInfo()` seems to be the only way to do it...

Answer (score 0):

Based on https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/iphlp/managing-network-adapters, you should be able to use the following:

- [`GetAdapterIndex`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/iphlpapi/nf-iphlpapi-getadapterindex)
- [`GetPerAdapterInfo`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/iphlpapi/nf-iphlpapi-getperadapterinfo)
- [`IP_PER_ADAPTER_INFO_W2KSP1`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/iptypes/ns-iptypes-ip_per_adapter_info_w2ksp1)
- [`IP_ADDR_STRING`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/iptypes/ns-iptypes-ip_addr_string)

Something like this should work:

```c
ULONG IfIndex = 0;
/* check error returned */ GetAdapterIndex(AdapterName, &IfIndex);
IP_PER_ADAPTER_INFO/*_W2KSP1?*/ PerAdapterInfo;
ULONG OutBufLen = sizeof(PerAdapterInfo);
/* check error returned */ GetPerAdapterInfo(IfIndex, &PerAdapterInfo, &OutBufLen);
/* check error returned */ DeleteIPAddress(PerAdapterInfo.DnsServerList.Context);
```

P.S. For older versions of Windows, this might work: https://microsoft.public.vb.winapi.narkive.com/TW7rVsdu/how-to-obtain-ntecontext-for-use-in-deleteipaddress-without-first-calling-addipaddress

Answer (score 0):

This [example](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/iphlpapi/nf-iphlpapi-getadaptersaddresses#examples) retrieves the IP_ADAPTER_ADDRESSES structure for the adapters associated with the system and prints some members for each adapter interface.

The following [example](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/iphlpapi/nf-iphlpapi-addipaddress#examples) retrieves the IP address table to determine the interface index for the first adapter, then adds the IP address specified on command line to the first adapter. The IP address that was added is then deleted.

I combined the two programs and modified the code.

It can output network card description, IP address, MAC address and DNS address. Also, it can add the IP address to the first adapter and delete the same address.
[image]

**Caution:**
The DeleteIPAddress() function deletes an IP address previously added using AddIPAddress().
If you just only use AddIPAddress() to add an IP address, after that you need to delete it manually.

This picture shows the IP added, and you can delete the added IP by “edit” on the left side.
[image]

Here is the code:

```
#pragma comment (lib, "Ws2_32.lib")
// Link with Iphlpapi.lib
#pragma comment(lib, "IPHLPAPI.lib")

#include<WinSock2.h>
#include<WS2tcpip.h>
#include<iostream>
#include<IPHlpApi.h>
using namespace std;
#pragma warning(disable:4996)
int main()
{
    PIP_ADAPTER_ADDRESSES pAddresses = nullptr;
    IP_ADAPTER_DNS_SERVER_ADDRESS* pDnServer = nullptr;
    ULONG outBufLen = 0;
    DWORD dwRetVal = 10;
    char buff[128];
    DWORD bufflen = 128;
    int i;

    PMIB_IPADDRTABLE pIPAddrTable;
    DWORD dwSize =128;
    
    UINT iaIPAddress;
    UINT imIPMask;

    ULONG NTEContext = 0;
    ULONG NTEInstance = 0;

    LPVOID lpMsgBuf;

    pIPAddrTable = (MIB_IPADDRTABLE*)VirtualAlloc(&dwSize, sizeof(PMIB_IPADDRTABLE), MEM_RESERVE, NULL);
    pIPAddrTable = (MIB_IPADDRTABLE*)malloc(150 * sizeof(MIB_IPADDRTABLE));
    GetAdaptersAddresses(AF_UNSPEC, 0, NULL, pAddresses, &outBufLen);

    pAddresses = (IP_ADAPTER_ADDRESSES*)malloc(outBufLen);

    if ((dwRetVal = GetAdaptersAddresses(AF_INET, GAA_FLAG_SKIP_ANYCAST, NULL, pAddresses, &outBufLen)) == NO_ERROR) {

        while (pAddresses) {
            printf("%S, %.2x-%.2x-%.2x-%.2x-%.2x-%.2x: \n",
                pAddresses->FriendlyName,
                pAddresses->PhysicalAddress[0], pAddresses->PhysicalAddress[1],
                pAddresses->PhysicalAddress[2], pAddresses->PhysicalAddress[3],
                pAddresses->PhysicalAddress[4], pAddresses->PhysicalAddress[5]);

            PIP_ADAPTER_UNICAST_ADDRESS pUnicast = pAddresses->FirstUnicastAddress;
            pDnServer = pAddresses->FirstDnsServerAddress;

            if (pDnServer)
            {
                sockaddr_in* sa_in = (sockaddr_in*)pDnServer->Address.lpSockaddr;
                printf("DNS:%s\n", inet_ntop(AF_INET, &(sa_in->sin_addr), buff, bufflen));
            }
            if (pAddresses->OperStatus == IfOperStatusUp)
            {
                printf("Status: active\n");
            }
            else
            {
                printf("Status: deactive\n");
            }


            for (i = 0; pUnicast != NULL; i++)
            {
                if (pUnicast->Address.lpSockaddr->sa_family == AF_INET)
                {
                    sockaddr_in* sa_in = (sockaddr_in*)pUnicast->Address.lpSockaddr;
                    printf("IPV4 Unicast Address:%s\n", inet_ntop(AF_INET, &(sa_in->sin_addr), buff, bufflen));
                }
                else if (pUnicast->Address.lpSockaddr->sa_family == AF_INET6)
                {
                    sockaddr_in6* sa_in6 = (sockaddr_in6*)pUnicast->Address.lpSockaddr;
                    printf("IPV6:%s\n", inet_ntop(AF_INET6, &(sa_in6->sin6_addr), buff, bufflen));
                }
                else
                {
                    printf("\tUNSPEC");
                }
                pUnicast = pUnicast->Next;
            }
            printf("Number of Unicast Addresses: %d\n", i);
            pAddresses = pAddresses->Next;
        }
    }
    else {
        LPVOID lpMsgBuf;
        printf("Call to GetAdaptersAddresses failed.\n");
        if (FormatMessage(
            FORMAT_MESSAGE_ALLOCATE_BUFFER |
            FORMAT_MESSAGE_FROM_SYSTEM |
            FORMAT_MESSAGE_IGNORE_INSERTS,
            NULL,
            dwRetVal,
            MAKELANGID(LANG_NEUTRAL, SUBLANG_DEFAULT),
            (LPTSTR)&lpMsgBuf,
            0,
            NULL)) {
            printf("\tError: %s", lpMsgBuf);
        }
        
    }
    if (GetIpAddrTable(pIPAddrTable, &dwSize, 0) == ERROR_INSUFFICIENT_BUFFER) 
    {
        GlobalFree(pIPAddrTable);
        
    }
    // Make a second call to GetIpAddrTable to get the
    // actual data we want
    if ((dwRetVal = GetIpAddrTable(pIPAddrTable, &dwSize, 0)) == NO_ERROR) {
        printf("\t Address: %d\n", pIPAddrTable->table[0].dwAddr);
        printf("\t Mask:    %d\n", pIPAddrTable->table[0].dwMask);
        printf("\t Index:   %d\n", pIPAddrTable->table[0].dwIndex);
        printf("\t BCast:   %d\n", pIPAddrTable->table[0].dwBCastAddr);
        printf("\t Reasm:   %d\n", pIPAddrTable->table[0].dwReasmSize);
    }
    else {
        printf("Call to GetIpAddrTable failed.\n");
    }

    // IP and mask we will be adding

    iaIPAddress = inet_addr("192.168.0.27");
    imIPMask = inet_addr("255.255.255.0");
    
    if ((dwRetVal = AddIPAddress(iaIPAddress,
        imIPMask,
        pIPAddrTable->table[0].dwIndex,
        &NTEContext, &NTEInstance)) == NO_ERROR) 
    {
        printf("\tIP address added.\n");
    }
    
    else {
       
        printf("Error adding IP address.\n");

        if (FormatMessage(
            FORMAT_MESSAGE_ALLOCATE_BUFFER | FORMAT_MESSAGE_FROM_SYSTEM | FORMAT_MESSAGE_IGNORE_INSERTS, 
            NULL, 
            dwRetVal, 
            MAKELANGID(LANG_NEUTRAL, SUBLANG_DEFAULT),       // Default language
            (LPTSTR)&lpMsgBuf, 
            0, 
            NULL))

        {
            
            printf(" Error: %d");
        }
        LocalFree(lpMsgBuf);
    }
    
    if ((dwRetVal = DeleteIPAddress(NTEContext)) == NO_ERROR)
    {
        printf("\t IP Address Deleted.\n");
    }
    else {
        
        printf("\t Call to DeleteIPAddress failed.\n");
    }
    
    free(pAddresses);
    VirtualFree(&dwSize, 0, MEM_RELEASE);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: This is not what the OP asked for as it uses the `NTEContext` returned from `AddIPAddress()` in order to delete the IP address.  What the OP wants (and me as well) is the `NTEContext` without first using `AddIPAddress()`.  I don't know why MS has made this so difficult...

Comment: @trojanfoe MSDN explained: To use DeleteIPAddress, AddIPAddress must first be called to get the handle `NTEContext`. The previous procedure assumes that AddIPAddress has already been called somewhere in the code, and `NTEContext` has been saved and remains uncorrupted.

Comment: It's not practical though in a situation where you want to provide a library to set interface addresses and later remove them, without the need to hold onto the `NTEContext` somehow.  The only way to do it seems to use `GetAdaptersInfo()`, which the docs warn you against using on Windows XP and later.